# Bootstrap Typeahead not working on dynamically added elements?

Tags: jquery, json, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-typeahead

I am adding an input box via an `onclick` function - so the input box isn't there when the page render's and when `document.ready()` fires.

I came up with a work-around by adding a `onclick` function to the input field that calls a javascript function.

`http://goo.gl/id6esq` will returns json:

> ["1175-1234567890","1175-1234567891","1175-1234567892","1175-1234567893","1175-1234567894","1175-1234567895"]

(I couldn't get a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kRSQZ/5/) working - won't do the typeahead)

```
<a id="clickbtn" class="btn-btn-inverse">Click me</a>

<div id="insert"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#clickbtn').on('click', function() {
            $('#insert').html("<input type='text' onclick='javascript:invoice_no_setup_typeahead($(this))' name='retrun-order-invoice_no' class='return-order-invoice_no' data-provide='typeahead'>");
        });
    });
    function invoice_no_setup_typeahead(self) {
        console.log('focus acheived');
        $(self).typeahead({
            source: function(query, process) {
                console.log(query);
                return $.get(
                        'http://goo.gl/id6esq', {
                    query: query
                },
                function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    return process(data);
                }, 'JSON');
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
    $('#clickbtn').on('click', function() {
        var el = $("<input type='text' name='retrun-order-invoice_no' class='return-order-invoice_no'>").appendTo($('#insert').empty());
        invoice_no_setup_typeahead(el)
    });
```

Comment: That did work! Thank you! Could you explain why it didn't work the first time? Would like to not run into this again?